# How to get the numeric position of char's

Tags: java, arrays, char

Say we have a bunch of char's: `'s', 'w', 'e', 's', 't', 'h'`

How can we see if we type a character via `(char)scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);`
at which places the numbers are(1,2,3,4,5,6). For example, if I type `w` I get `2` back, or if I type `s`, I get `1` and `4` back.

This is the code I already have:

```
   Scanner letter= new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Type a character:");
   char let= letter.nextLine().charAt(0);

   char[] word = {'s', 'w', 'a', 'g', 'w' };
   System.out.print();
```

Comment: Why dont you use `String word="swagw"` instead of your `Char Array`.

Comment: the teacher said we need to use char

Answer (score 0):

you can simple do it using map

```
        Map<Character,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Character,List<Integer>>();
```

then iterate on the character in the array and add their positions to the map with key the character like this

```
         if(map.get(word[i]) == null)//i is the index of the character
                    map.put(word[i],new ArrayList<Integer>());
          map.get(word[i]).add(i);
```

then when you insert your character you get the related list and print its content

Comment: This is far from simple, and considering how basic the question is, I don't think the OP is ready for this, nor do I think it would be suitable for their needs.

Comment: I respect your opinion and will vote you comment too

Comment: This is indeed too complicated than I can handle :p, i just started a week ago with java, thanks for the answer tho!

Comment: In my opinion you do not need the answer which you can understand, you need the answer which will set you in the right path , eventually you will understand it.

Comment: I know I have to learn the hard way but as it is right know i really can't figure out how to use your solution. Can you be kind enough to adjust it so i can use it and then understand it? greetings, Tom